# I have two dataframes representing two different time points. I want to run a linear regression model with data from both time points

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have two data frames representing two different timepoints, and I am wanting to run a linear regression model with data from two different timepoints.

timepoint_1 can be the first data frame, and timepoint_2 can be the second. I want to use the freq (frequency) data from the first timepoint, and I want to use the notes data from the first timepoint, but I want the instrument data from the second timepoint.

```
lm(freq~ notes+instrument+tuning, data =timepoint_1)
```

This is a silly example, but I am paranoid to post actual pictures of my actual data on here since we are trying to publish.

Ive tried to do something like this below, but it does not work

```
lm(freq~ notes+timepoint_1$instrument+tuning, data =timepoint_1)
```

Comment: If the two datasets can be linked (merged) using some common column or columns, then do that first and then run the model.

Comment: There are multiple ways to combine or merge data from two data.frames, depending on the structure of your data. Possibly, you could have an additional column of data representing "timepoint" (with values 1 or 2). Instead of posting pictures of data (we generally recommend *not* using images!), you can create example or "toy" data.frames demonstrating the columns and type of data that exist. That way you would not need to share any actual data.